# Писать местоимение "вы" с малой или большой буквы?

Tags: правописание

Мне когда-то кое-кто сказал, что писать "Вы" с большой буквы - подобострастно. Но я видел несколько раз, что пользователи этого сайта пишут это слово именно с большой буквы.

Как на самом деле?

/edit: В вопросе речь о местоимении "вы" в функции 2. лица единственного числа, например, когда обращаемся к одному человеку. Это и так ясно, что, обращаясь к группе людей, необходимо использовать "вы" с малой буквы.

Пример: корреспонденция майлом/личными сообщениями с пользователем форума, которого я не знаю в реальной жизни. Должен ли я писать "Вы", "вы" или просто "ты"?

Comment: В данном вопросе я полностью согласен с [Артемием](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/165/). Я буду обращаться к совершенно незнакомым людям на «вы», но «Вы» — это для стихов дамам из 19-го века

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll write in Russian, ОК?

Общеизвестно, что Вы (с заглавной) пишется при вежливом обращении к одному лицу. Но есть одна тонкость, про которую обычно забывают. 
Её по-разному формулируют - и это приводит к разночтениям. Я своими словами.

В основном правиле речь идет только о **личном** обращении к **конкретному** лицу.
Поэтому со строчной (маленькой) буквы вы пишется:
1. при передаче **устной речи** (в т.ч. в художественных текстах), а также в интернете, если стиль общения соответствуют устному (почти всегда на форумах, в скайпе и т. л., и часто во всякого рода социальных сетях),
2. при неконкретном обращении, предполагающем массового читателя, - типа памяток в гостинице или рекламы,
3. в рассылках.
Отдельным пунктом раньше стояли анкеты, сейчас, вроде, пришли к выводу, что там следует использовать заглавную.

К сожалению, эти правила нигде в одном месте явно не сформулированы, вынужден лично ликвидировать этот недочет.

При написании e-мэйла одному человеку, коли уж Вы используете "вы", писать стоит с заглавной.

Answer (score 9):

Rosenthal, 28:

> С прописной буквы пишутся местоимения *Вы* и *Ваш* для выражения вежливого обращения к одному лицу, например: *Прошу Вас, уважаемый Сергей Петрович…*
>
> При обращении к нескольким лицам эти местоимения пишутся со строчной буквы, например: *Прошу вас, уважаемые Сергей Петрович и Павел Иванович…*

Note that this rule is only applied to *вы* used towards the addressee in a personal letter, not in any writing.

This means that in a direct speech lowercase *вы* is used:

> Г. Зеленко: ― К какой глубине вы относите сино-тибетские языки? // *Сергей Старостин, Григорий Зеленко. У человечества был один праязык // «Знание -- сила», 2003*

Also, many people, myself included, choose to perceive Internet forum communication as a transcript of live conversation rather than a series or letters. Thus, those people (and I) use uppercase *Вы* in emails but lowercase on forums and instant messengers.

Comment: Человек задал вопрос по-русски. Полагаю, ему можно по-английски не писать.

Comment: @Paul: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! This site is aimed at non-native speakers. We do allow Russian questions and answers, but many of us prefer to ask and answer in English so that the answers could be found and understood by those not well versed in Russian. We have a sister site, http://rus.stackexchange.com , which is completely in Russian. Questions that specifically ask for Russian answers are migrated there.

Comment: Speaking of Internet forums, writing Вы from capital could have a meaning of mocking or sarcasm.

Comment: And what about private messages (личные сообщения)? Are they treated as letters or as a part of conversation?

Comment: @marmistrz: I (I personally) use lowercase anywhere except emails. To me, an email is a hi-tech version of a written personal letter, a forum message is a hi-tech version of a live conversation (public or private, does not matter).

Answer (score 4):

При обращении к одному человеку "Вы" с заглавной буквы пишется в трёх случаях:

- в начале предложения
- в официальных письмах
- в знак особого уважения

В остальных случаях пишите "вы" со строчной буквы.

"Тыкать" (обращаться на ты) в форуме можно только если человек на это согласился. Например, в профайле может стоять "предпочитаю обращение на ты".

Ну или если он называет вас на "ты", вы можете или предложить обращаться на "вы", или тоже начать ему тыкать.

Answer (score 3):

Я хочу отметить, что "Вы" в интернете часто пишут, чтоб подчеркнуть дистанцию и некое превосходство. Тон при этом может быть весьма агрессивным/высокомерным и совсем неуважительным.

Из серии: "А Вы, батенька, обычным дурачком оказались. Я Вас больше не задерживаю."

Тогда как в обычной беседе этот же человек будет использовать просто "вы".

Answer (score 2):

С большой буквы пишут, если уважают собеседника (например, старше по возрасту или незнакомый человек). С маленькой буквы пишут, если это группа людей.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use Вы when you speak to one person, and вы when you speak to group of people. "Люди, что вы делаете?" but "Иван Петрович, Вы забыли Вашу шляпу"

Comment: How do you differentiate them when speaking?

Comment: Both words sound absolutelly the same, so you can not differentiate them except by context.

Comment: it's just that you say you somehow know when to use one or another when *speaking*. Did you mean "when writing"?

Comment: Direct speech is written without capitalization of "вы" if those words aren't a quote from someone's letter, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Тот факт, что вы уважаете собеседника, уже достаточно выражен тем, что вы обращаетесь к нему на "вы", а не на "ты". Поэтому излишнее подчеркивание с помощью заглавной буквы - это, действительно, подобострастно. Вполне подойдет для обращения к президенту, патриарху, епископу, королю (или королеве). Использовалось для обращений к титулованным особам. Так получилось, что знать у нас исчезла, а желание писать "Вы" не пропало. Это типичная для носителей языка ошибка. 
Btw, в руководстве для переводчиков субтитров на coursera есть фраза: "Представьте себе, что слова "Вы" не существует, а слово "вы" - существует", вполне отражающая тот факт, насколько такое написание ошибочно и насколько эта ошибка частотна. :) 
Fell free to ask for a translation if needed.